# Disable SourceMaps for one specific vendor in Angular

Tags: angular, source-maps, angular7

I'm using Angular 7 in my project, there is one specific dependency that has some broken Source Map files.
I want to disable the source maps but just for that specific dependency.

I found there is a configuration (in the angular.json file):

```
"vendorSourceMap": true
```

If I change that to false I can disable that library but also several other libraries.

I want just to disable one specific dependency.

Is it possible?